# How to update previous screen params from current screen in react-navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

In `react-navigation` 4, I was passing a `function` as a param to the navigated screen. But in react-navigation 5, this has a warning which is not recommended. So now how can I update params of previous screen from current screen ?

Example:

1. I am in a chat group.
2. I click on group image.
3. In the new screen I update group name.
4. Now I return back by clicking `hardware back button`.
5. And now the group name should be new updated name.

So how this is possible ??

I know I can use `navigation.navigate()` to go back with params, but in most cases there users use clicking on hardware back button instead of clicking the back arrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new way to handle Hardware Back Button described here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-android-back-button-handling.html#__docusaurus

But I don't think you should go this way. You should connect the group name to a local storage, and watch this variable in the render function. It's better to let the render to update itself instead of trying to do some force refresh with the back handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a store (using redux, hooks or using local storage). Then you can use Navigation events => focus method when the screen comes into focus. Then you can get the updated store data and re-render the UI.

Comment: I know as you said, but here is list of groups and we have list of groups dynamically, so when I click on a group the group chat gets opened and there is not special global var for group name image and etc.